# Bootstrap 3 - table with images in 4 columns aren't responsive

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

Instead of setting up one after another, by reducing the screen images stretch unnatural (and stay in 4 columns).

I paste a piece of code with only 2 pictures, because otherwise stackoverflow blocking publication of the post.

Thanks in advance

```html
 <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                <div class="viewport">
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="dark-background" style="display: none;">Northern Saw-whet Owl <em>Photo by Matt Bango</em></span>
                        <img src="images/portfolio/image1.jpg" alt="Northern Saw-Whet Owl" class="img-portfolio-item" />
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-3">
                <div class="viewport">
                    <a href="#">
                        <span class="dark-background" style="display: none;">Northern Saw-whet Owl <em>Photo by Matt Bango</em></span>
                        <img src="images/portfolio/image2.jpg" alt="Northern Saw-Whet Owl" class="img-portfolio-item" />
                    </a>
                </div>
            </div>    

        </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: add a bootply.com or jsbin.com or jsfiddle.net playground. also add the custom css and js if you used any.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per your comment, if you use

```
<img src="images/portfolio/image3.jpg" alt="Northern Saw-Whet Owl" class="img-portfolio-item" class="img-responsive" />
```

it will ignore the second image tag. Instead use:

```
<img src="images/portfolio/image3.jpg" alt="Northern Saw-Whet Owl" class="img-portfolio-item img-responsive" />
```

Also, you've made the column `col-xs-3` which means that it will be 4 columns from 0px. To make the image 100% width up until the first (small) breakpoint, use `col-sm-3`instead.

So:

```
...
<div class="col-sm-3">
  <div class="viewport">
    <a href="#">
      <span class="dark-background" style="display: none;">Northern Saw-whet Owl <em>Photo by Matt Bango</em></span>
      <img src="images/portfolio/image1.jpg" alt="Northern Saw-Whet Owl" class="img-portfolio-item" />
    </a>
  </div>
</div>
...
```

Comment: Please see amended answer

Answer (score 0):

Use class="img-responsive" on img tags. See [doc](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#images-responsive) for more info

Comment: I forgot to write, I have tried this: <img src="images/portfolio/image3.jpg" alt="Northern Saw-Whet Owl" class="img-portfolio-item" class="img-responsive" />   or     <img src="images/portfolio/image3.jpg" alt="Northern Saw-Whet Owl"  class="img-responsive" />    - it doesn't work.